# кодировка в JSP и String

Tags: jsp, java

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Если jsp-страничка :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Строки</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% 
        String inputName = request.getParameter("name");

        if (inputName == null) {
    %>
        <form action="HelloVasiliyJSP.jsp" method="get">
            <p>Введите строку</p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                <input type="submit" value="Окей" />
            </p>
        </form>
    <% } else { 
        String newString = "Новая строка";
    %>
        <h1>Java String функции</h1>
        <p>newString</p>
        <ul>
            <li><%=newString%></li>
            <li>toLowerCase() : <%=newString.toLowerCase()%></li>
            <li>toUpperCase() : <%=newString.toUpperCase()%></li>
        </ul>
        <p>inputName</p>
        <ul>
            <li><%=inputName%></li>
            <li>toLowerCase() : <%=inputName.toLowerCase()%></li>
            <li>toUpperCase() : <%=inputName.toUpperCase()%></li>
        </ul>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

в кодировке UTF-8. Страница, если не находит параметр запроса `name`, выводит форму для ввода этого параметра и сабмитит на сама себя. Если находит `name`, читает его в строку `inputString` и проводит над ней простые оперцаии: вывод, `toLowerCase()` и `toUpperCase()`. Если строка английская, все Ок. А вот если в ней русские симоволы, отрабатывает она не корректно (результат преобразований возвращается "абру-катабру"). Проблема, я так понимаю, в кодировке, но как ее привести к нормальному виду?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, надо выставить кодировку самой JSP-страницы

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

Во-вторых, можно указать кодировку на входе:

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

И в третьих, так вообще не делается. Входные параметры принято брать через EL-expressions:

```
${params['name']}
```

И, наконец, вы совершенно не думаете об XSS, а очень зря.

Comment: Спасибо. Первые два пункта помогли. Про XSS не думал, пример учебный.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы используете Apache Tomcat в качестве веб-сервера, неплохо еще указать HTTP-коннектору использовать UTF-8 при разборе URL, так как вы используете GET-запрос для отправки данных на сервер. Подробнее смотрите [тут](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) (URIEncoding).